# ¿Cómo Prevenir carga de fragmento en "blanco" con popBackStack en Android?

Tags: java, android

Tengo un sistema de navegación lateral, mediante carga de fragmentos usando la propiedad `addToBackStack` para así cuando se pulse el botón atrás, se recupere el último fragmento de la pila de control de fragmentos con el método `getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack()`.

El problema es que cuando no queda fragmentos en la pila no sale de la aplicación y se muestra la aplicación como si se cargase un fragmento en blanco, se necesita otro pulsación atrás para salir de la aplicación.

¿Cómo puedo prevenir la carga del fragmento en blanco y salga de la aplicación si ya no queda más fragmentos en la pila?

El código de control de `onBackPressed` en MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBackPressed()");

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        Log.d(TAG, "close Drawer");
    } else {
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1 ){
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();

            Log.d(TAG, "fragment Manager popBackStack()");
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

con respecto a tu pregunta :

> **¿Cómo Prevenir carga de fragmento en “blanco” con popBackStack en Android?**

[`finish()`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()), es exclusivo para cerrar la Activity y funciona, pero únicamente estas cerrando la Activity.

**la solución real sería no agregar el primer fragmento al stack, con esto solucionas el problema realmente.**

Comment: Buenos dias @Elenasys, no había caído con eso, si no se carga a la pila, siempre estará allí, probaré si lo ser aplicar

Answer (score 4):

~~Solucionado, remplazar `super.onBackPressed();` por `finish()` y así se fuerza el cierre de la aplicación.~~

**Edit**

La carga del primer fragmento realizarla con `add` y las otras con `replace`.

```
private void addFragment(Fragment newFragment) {
    Log.i(TAG, "addFragment() called with: newFragment = [" + newFragment + "]");
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.frame_container, newFragment);
    ft.commit();
}

private void replaceFragment(Fragment newFragment) {
    Log.i(TAG, "replaceFragment() called with: newFragment = [" + newFragment + "]");
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, newFragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(newFragment.getClass().getName());
    ft.commit();
}
```